# How to fix the Rails text helper 'truncate' after upgrading to Snow Leopard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard

I just upgraded to Snow Leopard and went to edit some code on a legacy Rails app (1.2.5) and found that the views cause a crash when trying to render the 'truncate' text helper.  I took them out and it rendered fine.  How do you fix this? Are there other methods that might see the same issue?

Comment: What errors are getting logged?

Comment: undefined method `length’ for Enumerable Enumerator on text_helper.rb:50:in `truncate’

Answer (score 1):

I found this bit of code which seems to be the fix, however I'm wondering if there is a less hackish way to do it.

```
# place the following code at the end of your config/environment.rb

module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module TextHelper
      def truncate(text, length = 30, truncate_string = "...")
        if text.nil? then return end
        l = length - truncate_string.chars.to_a.size
        (text.chars.to_a.size > length ? text.chars.to_a[0...l].join + truncate_string : text).to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this is probably the best way to do it. Rails versions less than 2.2 are not compatible with Ruby 1.8.7.